# Do Bases and Acids actually react with each other?

Tags: acid-base, titration

Let's say we have $5$ $\ce{HCl}$ molecules and we dump them into a container full of water. It's a strong acid so all $5$ $\ce{H+}$ ions would react with water and create $\ce{H3O+}$. It reacts with the water, right?

Now, we add $5$ $\ce{NaOH}$ molecules down there. They all react with some water molecules of their own as well and create $5$ $\ce{OH-}$. So now we have $5$ $\ce{H3O+}$ and $5$ $\ce{OH-}$. Those two don't react with each other, correct? They just react with the water molecules and balance each other out, giving us a neutral solution.

I am unsure of this. Is this true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They certainly react with each other: $$\ce{H3O+ + OH- -> 2H2O}$$

Comment: Hmm ... so they react separately with water molecules and then the products react with each other?

Comment: Yes. The steps would be: $$\ce{HCl + H2O -> H3O+ + Cl-}$$ $$\ce{NaOH -> Na+ + OH-}$$ $$\ce{H3O+ + OH- -> 2H2O}$$

Comment: Thank you. But is it then wrong to say that acids and bases balance each other out in a solution and thereby make it neutral? Provided we have an equilibrium

Comment: That question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hahah, ok. I was always taught in school that a pH of 7 means that the concentration of $ OH^- $ and $ H_3O^+ $ is identical.

Comment: That is true.$ $

Comment: So is it wrong to say that during a titration, when an equilibirum has been reached, that the acid and base have 'balanced each other out'? Or is it more correct to say all available $ H^+ $ have reacted with all available $ OH^- $?

Comment: pH  7 **does not** mean that the concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{H3O+}$ is identical. pH is defined as $$\mathrm{pH = -\log{[H_3O^+]}}$$ The amount of autoionisation of water varies with temperature hence so does the pH. Neutrality is defined as having $\ce{[H3O+] = [OH-]}$, *not* as pH = 7.

Comment: Pretty sure that's what I said ... or meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ce{NaOH + HCl -> NaCl + H2O}$$

$$\ce{Na+ + Cl- + OH- + H+ -> Na+ + Cl- + H2O_{(l)}}$$
Both sides $\ce{Na+}$ ans $\ce{Cl-}$ cancel out remaining reaction

$$\ce{H+ + OH- <=> H2O_{(l)}}$$

Any strong acid and strong base reaction the remaining reaction is hydrolization of water.